# SQL Join -Always return data from first table for each row in the second table

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables tblSettingsLookup and tblFirm.
I have 5 settings in the lookuptable,which is basically used to reneder setting names dynamically. E.g. If there are 5 settings then each firm can see five settings on some page.If I add a new setting ,now all firms would see 6 settings.

I have a page that gets all settings from the tblSettingsLookup and user can select these settings from a web page in my application via checkboxes and save it int the database.
These user settings  are saved in another table tblusersettingsforfirms

tblusersettingsforfirm has settingIDFK,firmIDFK,and some other columns
tblSettingsLookup has settingID,setting name
tblFirm  has FirmID

What I actually need to do is that I want one query that returns all records from tblSettingsLookup and all user settings for firm based on firmID.

I have tried left outer joins but no hope.I dont need cross joins

The result should be something as follows:

```
firmid settingname      
1      add user
1      delete user
1      save user
2      add user
2      save user
2      delete user
```

Comment: -- edit my mistake you had me confused --

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a cross join and a left join:

```
select f.FirmID, l.settingname, u.settingIDFK
from
  tblFirm as f
  cross join tblSettingsLookup as l
  left join tblusersettingsforfirms u
    on u.settingIDFK = l.settingID and u.firmIDFK = f.FirmID
```

The value returned for `u.settingIDFK` will be null if there is no user setting. You might want to return some other value from that table there.

Example result:

```
firmID  settingname  settingIDFK
1       add user     42
1       delete user  null
1       save user    76
2       add user     14
2       save user    null
2       delete user  null
```

To filter out the data for a specific firm, you just add a `where` clause. Example:

```
select f.FirmID, l.settingname, u.settingIDFK
from
  tblFirm as f
  cross join tblSettingsLookup as l
  left join tblusersettingsforfirms u
    on u.settingIDFK = l.settingID and u.firmIDFK = f.FirmID
where f.firmID = 15
```

Comment: Let me try...i think this might be it

Comment: Can you please tell me how to apply the filter so that it gives me the data for firm 15 such that the settingIDFK which are null for firm 15 are aslo returned??And I will accept your answer as this is exactly what I want...please help me out with the filter.I tried to add a where cluse but it ommits the nulls.

Comment: ...can ypu please help out in filtering the result

Comment: @abbas: I added an example in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
    SELECT `tblFirm`.`firmid`, `tblusersettingsforfirm`.`settingname`  
    FROM `tblFirm`, `tblusersettingsforfirm`
    WHERE (`tblFirm`.`firmid` =  
    `tblusersettingsforfirm`.`firmIDFK`)
```

Comment: No.I want reults likeI mentioned in the question.Table 1 should always return values.

Answer (score 0):

While your description is not that clear (it would help to show the data in the two tables you want to join along with the expected output), it *sounds* to me like you want to simply show one instance of each setting record for each firm.  That is, in fact, a cross join (or cartesian product):

```
 SELECT tblFirm.FirmID, tblSettingsLookup.setting_name
   FROM tblFirm, tblSettingsLookup
```

Comment: That's correct.  Because there is no point of commonality between the two tables (at least, as I understand your original question), you simply "multiply" the rows by leaving off the JOIN expression.

Comment: Thanks you broght me really close to a solution...Not the excatly what I wanted but it would give a kick start